# How can I adjust the number of threads with pytest + xdist?

Tags: pytest, xdist, pytest-xdist, pytest-asyncio

To run parallel tests on mobile devices, I use pytest + xdist.

I want to run *as many threads as I have connected devices*, no more.

I pass "-n 4" as command line argument, but I can't change it after test launch if I need 2 threads, not 4.

How can I adjust the number of threads from the my test code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [this](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#dynamically-adding-command-line-options).

Comment: Unfortunately, this hook will not be called for conftest.py files, only for setuptools plugins.

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_load_initial_conftests


So, I don't understand how use this hook in the conftest.py

Comment: Oh, so that means the documentation is not correct. Because on that page, they have specified `# content of conftest.py`.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a minimal way to know it in python, i propose creating a python script that will call pytest.main with the correct arguments